# delphi Ado update insert betwen 2 records

Tags: delphi, dataset

I need to update records from one table to the other (this for the master Table and f«the same for the DetailTable.

first a position the record of the record´s of the table I want to copy update from:

Tabelamestre(Local_deste_cliente) (1 record )

```
NInterv.text:=dbedit1.text;

 Begin
   with  ADOTable_casa do  
      Begin
        Close;
        SQL.Clear;
        SQL.Add('SELECT * from  Vibrometria_');
        SQL.Add('Where numeracao LIKE ''%'+NInterv.text );
        Open;
       end;
 end
```

now i need to update/insert  the record´s from  **Vibrometria :=  Local_deste_cliente  (TADOTABLE)**
Now i need to get the record above and do the same for the 2 detail tables

```
    Vibrometria_Sub (J)  :=   Tabeladetail  (Variaveis_neste_local). ((J) Records
```

and i stil have another table thar get a master record from (K)  Tabeladetail  (Variaveis_neste_local)

```
Vibrometria_Sub1 (K)  :=   Tabeladetail1(Variaveis_neste_local1). ((k) Records
```

lest´s say i need to update 1 to N starting in the first table!!!!!!!!

is there a fast solution for this!!!!!!

Thanks

Comment: ¿están todas las tablas en la misma base de datos?
¿se hace algún procesamiento adicional con las llaves primarias o solamente se "traslada" la información tal como está de una a otra?

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Create the child records in the master dataset's AfterInsert() event.

Use the MasterSource and MasterFields property of the child dataset to automatically change the records when the master record changes.

Comment: can you explain how to do that!! please